# Передать в printf аргументы принятые в функции

Tags: c++, c

Есть небольшая функция логирования, в которую как и в `printf`, `sprintf` и т.д. можно передать неограниченное число аргументов.

Как переданные аргумены передать в функцию `printf`?

```
typedef enum console_color : unsigned
{
    black = 0,
    blue = 1,
    green = 2,
    cyan = 3,
    red = 4,
    magenta = 5,
    brown = 6,
    light_gray = 7,
    dark_gray = 8,
    light_blue = 9,
    light_green = 10,
    light_cyan = 11,
    light_red = 12,
    light_magenta = 13,
    yellow = 14,
    white = 15
} console_color;

typedef enum LogCategory
{
    info = 0x0,
    warning,
    error,
    critical
} LogCategory;

inline int Log(const LogCategory cat, const char* fmt, ...)
{
    void* h_console = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    console_color bg = black, fg = light_gray;
    int result = 0;
    switch (cat)
    {
    case info:
        fg = light_gray;
        break;
    case warning:
        fg = yellow;
        break;
    case error:
        fg = red;
        break;
    case critical:
        bg = red;
        fg = white;
        break;
    default: ;
    }
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(h_console, static_cast<WORD>(bg << static_cast<uint32_t>(4) | fg));
    result = printf_s(fmt, ...);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(h_console, static_cast<WORD>(black << static_cast<uint32_t>(4) | light_gray));
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Посмотри в сторону `__va_args__`. Но если с ++ более важен, чем с, то тут только шаблоны.

Comment: В `printf` уже никак не передать. Передавать придется в `vprintf` - специально для этого она и создана.

Comment: В printf уже никак не передать средствами с++. Можно средствами ассемблера, если "подвинуть" окно стека, предварительно вернув окну изначальный вид (если окно испорчено try или другими функциями), и передать управление printf. это достаточно долго. Поэтому тоже советую vprintf.

Comment: Через макрос можно передать и в printf, `#define prn(A,...) printf(A,__VA_ARGS__)` В вашем случае часть функции придеться уносить в макрос.

Comment: И console_color удобнее выбирать не switch'ом, а сделать инт массив по размеру LogCategory. Выбор соответственно будет = array[cat]

Comment: @NewView: "Часть функции"? В таком случае придется "уносить в макрос" *всю* функцию.

Comment: Её можно поделить на функциональные части, кстати, с писанием логов это распространённая практика, например чтоб в аргументы добавить текущее время, имя функции откуда вызвано, номер строки, имя файла итд.

Comment: Переделывать VA_arg массив себе дороже, проверено, легче сразу уйти в asm  и от туда разбирать стек вызова.